# Allwinner A13 hang on boot and return "SPL:Unsupported Boot Device!" error

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, boot, bootloader, u-boot

I am new in here and I am sorry my bad English.

I have OLinuXino A13 board. I endeavor kernel and boot events. So I try boot OLinuxino-A13 via spiflash(in FEL mode). I connected board to my PC(USB OTG). I Sending commands from my computer for writing to spiflash. And differently I build second connect with usb-ttl. So I can see opening writing of board with `CuteCom` program from my PC. And I use `sunxi-tools` for write to spiflash of my board.

And I did this:

I compiled kernel and I created `u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin` file. After I entered FEL mode and I wrote this file to on my board with `./sunxi-fel spiflash-write 0 /path/u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin`. When I use boot my board from PC with `./sunxi-fel uboot /path/u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin`, my board start and it work for find to sd card. Result this:

```
U-Boot SPL 2019.04-rc1-00141-g63f7e3fca3 (Feb 19 2019 - 17:23:48 +0300)
DRAM: 512 MiB
CPU: 1008000000Hz, AXI/AHB/APB: 3/2/2
Trying to boot from FEL


U-Boot 2019.04-rc1-00141-g63f7e3fca3 (Feb 19 2019 - 17:23:48 +0300) Allwinner Technology

CPU:   Allwinner A13 (SUN5I)
Model: Olimex A13-Olinuxino
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
MMC:   mmc@1c0f000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... MMC: no card present
Setting up a 1024x768 vga console (overscan 0x0)
In:    serial
Out:   vga
Err:   vga
Allwinner mUSB OTG (Peripheral)
Net:   
Warning: usb_ether using MAC address from ROM
eth0: usb_ether
starting USB...
USB0:   USB EHCI 1.00
USB1:   USB OHCI 1.0
scanning bus 0 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
scanning bus 1 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
   scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  2 <0x08><0x08><0x08> 1 <0x08><0x08><0x08> 0 
MMC: no card present

Device 0: unknown device
```

But differently if I restart my board after(card is out of fel mode) `./sunxi-fel spiflash-write 0 /path/u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin` command. Result this:

```
U-Boot SPL 2019.04-rc1-00141-g63f7e3fca3 (Feb 19 2019 - 17:23:48 +0300)
DRAM: 512 MiB
CPU: 1008000000Hz, AXI/AHB/APB: 3/2/2
SPL: Unsupported Boot Device!
SPL: failed to boot from all boot devices
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

A13-OLinuxino_defconfig file:

```
CONFIG_ARM=y
CONFIG_ARCH_SUNXI=y
CONFIG_SPL=y
CONFIG_MACH_SUN5I=y
CONFIG_DRAM_CLK=408
CONFIG_DRAM_EMR1=0
CONFIG_MMC0_CD_PIN="PG0"
CONFIG_USB0_VBUS_DET="PG1"
CONFIG_USB1_VBUS_PIN="PG11"
CONFIG_AXP_GPIO=y
# CONFIG_VIDEO_HDMI is not set
CONFIG_VIDEO_VGA_VIA_LCD=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_VGA_VIA_LCD_FORCE_SYNC_ACTIVE_HIGH=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_LCD_POWER="AXP0-0"
CONFIG_VIDEO_LCD_BL_PWM="PB2"
CONFIG_NR_DRAM_BANKS=1
# CONFIG_SYS_MALLOC_CLEAR_ON_INIT is not set
CONFIG_SPL_I2C_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_CMD_DFU=y
# CONFIG_CMD_FLASH is not set
CONFIG_CMD_USB_MASS_STORAGE=y
# CONFIG_SPL_DOS_PARTITION is not set
# CONFIG_SPL_PARTITION_UUIDS is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE="sun5i-a13-olinuxino"
CONFIG_DFU_RAM=y
CONFIG_FASTBOOT_CMD_OEM_FORMAT=y
CONFIG_AXP_ALDO3_VOLT=3300
CONFIG_CONS_INDEX=2
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_MUSB_GADGET=y
CONFIG_SYS_USB_EVENT_POLL_VIA_INT_QUEUE=yONFIG_AXP_ALDO3_VOLT=3300
CONFIG_CONS_INDEX=2
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_MUSB_GADGET=y
CONFIG_SYS_USB_EVENT_POLL_VIA_INT_QUEUE=y
```

I struggle for exceed this error and want to see result like on above. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you have SPL_SPI_SUNXI enabled?  Please post the full config you're using with this problem, thanks!

Comment: @TomRini edit my post . I saw that SPL_SPI_SUNXI is not in the my defconfig file. I added but so I could not update defconfig file. `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf` does not work now. I researched this. Also Can I enabled SPL_SPI_SUNXI in `make menufile` ?

Comment: @TomRini You are right. I searched SPL_SPI_SUNXI in `make menuconfig`, I enabled and board can boot from spi-flahs. Thanks :)